# Got git push error: "You cannot push the following commits as they are authored by users not known to Stash by author name"

Tags: git, bitbucket

My command was `git push -u origin feature_branch`. In addition to the error message in the title, I also got the following messages:

```
Check your gitconfig has the correct author name, or contact an administrator
```

The gitconfig is correct and just to be positive I copy-pasted the username and email from bitbucket and tried again.

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://companyname.com...'
```

I checked and confirmed that the repo I'm pushing to does not have any pre-receive hooks configured at all.

I can clone the repo without issue, it's only when I try to push changes that I get this error. I don't know enough about git to know where I should start looking to narrow down the problem other than what the error messages already suggested.

Comment: Maybe the `master` branch is protected and cannot be pushed to?

Comment: @RBCunhaDesign I checked "branch permissions" and it says there are none. Is that enough to conclude it's not protected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the user name the repo was expecting was different than the one set up in bitbucket. This isn't really something that happens on github as far as I know, but the repo was set up so you use an SSH key for authentication, then commit under the name from the corporate records. I made sure they names matched, but I had the unstated assumption that they were supposed to match, which wasn't true.

Answer (score 1):

This is total speculation, but...

A pre-receive hook can't actually see your git *config*, it can only see the user names and email addresses on commits.  Your push request (presumably) asks them to create their `feature_branch` name.  They have a pre-receive hook—that's where this message and failure all come from—that sees your request to create this branch name and inspects some set of commits.  Exactly *which* set of commits, and *how* it inspects them, are known only to the pre-receive hook itself.  (It might be helpful if its diagnostics told you which commits it did not like.)  But again, *guessing*, I'll say that they used:

```
git rev-list <hash-id> --not --all
```

which would get them the hash IDs of any commits reachable from the tip of the branch you're pushing that are not reachable from any of their own branch-tips.  If you run:

```
git fetch origin
```

and then:

```
git log --pretty=fuller feature_branch --not --remotes=origin
```

that will show you which commits you're sending for your `feature_branch` that are not in any of their own branches, which would be the set of commits they're inspecting.  The `--pretty=fuller` will have your Git show you both the author and committer lines for each such commit.

Inspecting those may be helpful, because it's probably exactly those things that their own pre-receive hook is inspecting and rejecting.

Again, *nobody but whoever controls this pre-receive hook can be sure about this* because we cannot see the pre-receive hook code.  We only see its *output*, which was the line you quoted at the start:

> ```
> Check your gitconfig has the correct author name, or contact an administrator
> ```

From this, we—by this I mean to include you as well: everyone who's *not* in control of this pre-receive hook—all have to guess *what* their pre-receive hook does not like about your request to their Git to have their Git create the name `feature_branch`, pointing to some specific commit hash ID.